# Using Subforms and Subreports is causing enter parameter value popup

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

I have a Microsoft 2010 Access database that I'm making to determine the Cost of Goods for soap recipes.  I have 3 tables `Ingredients` `Recipe` and `RecipeLines`.  From these tables, I have several queries that I've made to give me the information I need...ounces per ingredient, cost of ingredient per recipe, cost of ingredient per ounce, cost of bar per ingredient, etc.  I created a recipe report that shows me every recipe in the database, it's ingredients, how much the recipe costs and how much per bar of soap.  It was working fine and then I closed it out, and opened the report back up and it keeps asking me for the `RecipeID`.  I has to be from one of the subreports/subforms on that report.  What's weird is that if I add a text field and set it's control source to `RecipeID` everything works.  However, if I close the db and open it back up, I get the same dialogue box.  I have to assume that one of my subreport/subforms is causing the issue but how do I fix it?  If I open any of the subreports/subforms they all work but then again, they're not looking for a `RecipeID` to tie it to.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm not an expert in Access at all so please forgive me.

Comment: Have you read this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-Access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-a7344543-e758-4785-8433-420eb0f0b48e Quite often it happens when you change the name of something, like a field name and then some formula or expression you're using is still trying to reference the old name.

Comment: Matt, I did read that and it didn't really help. I THINK the problem is that I have 3 separate subreports/subforms that are looking at the recipeid.  What I don't understand is why if I delete the recipeid on the form and readd it, it works?  But when I close out the db and reopen it, the problem reappears.

Comment: Are you able to share your project with us?

Comment: Matt, I would share the project however, I took the project home where my wife will be using it and it seems to be working fine without any problem.  I can open up the report and there are no errors at all.  I have no idea why it's doing it on my work system but it's fine at home so I guess it's good.  I'm running 2010 at work and 2013 at home so maybe it's something with the older version.  Sorry but thank you for your help.